# Maps Not Showing

Tags: javascript, magento-1.7

I purchased a Map to use on Magento 1.7.2. I am having problems getting it to work on CMS Page Called Maps. The maps has two java files mapdata.js and namap.js and a command The Map.

**A Test Working Map:** http://www.webstertoolbox.com/testmap/map.html

I put the The Map in the the CMS Page called Map in Content part of the cms page. I have also added the java include files to the "Update Layout XML" like so:

```
<reference name="head">
<action method="addItem">
<type>skin_js</type>
<name>js/mapdata.js</name>
<params/>
</action>
</reference>
<reference name="head">
<action method="addItem">
<type>skin_js</type>
<name>js/namap.js</name>
<params/>
</action>
</reference>
```

You can find the page here: http://www.webstertoolbox.com/index.php/maps
The map site installer is here: http://simplemaps.com/docs/typical-install

I know the XML is loading the java files because when I view the source the two files are there. I know its reading the div as well because its show "The Map" on the page. I also created a folder called map_images in the same location of the js files. Now I have tested the map myself on my local browser and it worked fine. Looking at Googles Inspect I see there 4 errors but not sure why or how to fix them. Could any please tell my why this isn't working?

**The Errors in Google are:**

Viewport argument value "device-width;" for key "width" is invalid, and has been ignored. Note that ';' is not a separator in viewport values. The list should be comma-separated. maps:6'

Uncaught ReferenceError: eve is not defined maps:1
chrome.tabs is not available: You do not have permission to access this API. Ensure that the required permission or manifest property is included in your manifest.json. [VM] binding (14211):216

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined measureIt.js:120

Thanks,

Frank

Comment: What are the errors you are seeing?

Comment: Viewport argument value "device-width;" for key "width" is invalid, and has been ignored. Note that ';' is not a separator in viewport values. The list should be comma-separated. maps:6
Uncaught ReferenceError: eve is not defined maps:1
chrome.tabs is not available: You do not have permission to access this API. Ensure that the required permission or manifest property is included in your manifest.json. [VM] binding (14211):216
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined measureIt.js:120
DOIT http://www.webstertoolbox.com/index.php/maps

Comment: I updated my posted with the errors. Any ideas why it wont load?

Comment: Here is a test working map: http://www.webstertoolbox.com/testmap/map.html if this helps. Thanks again for your help!